# Cant train with GPU in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on a CNN, and I noticed that during the training phase it uses CPU 100% instead of GPU (I have a GTX 1660Ti).

## Tensorflow doesn't recognize my 1660Ti

I tried to follow [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu) from TensorFlow website.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

outputs

```
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

I tried to read **all devices** recognized by TensorFlow

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices()
```

outputs

```
[ PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU') ]
```

## What i read on the topic

Searching in the internet I found that maybe I had to install **NVidia CUDA toolkit**. I did it from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit), but it didn't solve it.

I found that **NVidia CUDA** is not always enabled on all GPUs: [source](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus). I found that a little strange, why should NVidia cut off a part of their customers from using CUDA?

## Additional informations

My **requirements.txt** (if software version can help to solve my problems):

```
matplotlib==3.4.2
keras==2.4.3
tensorflow-gpu==2.5.0
seaborn==0.11.1
```

I'm running the python code in a **Jupyter Notebook** (installed via pip)

## My question

There's a way to use my GPU for CUDA (or at least use TensorFlow, like in this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Finally solved it.

I had to download cuDNN from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download), and following [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html) installation guide I finally got it working.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

now outputs

```
Num GPUs Available:  1
```

and

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices()
```

now outputs

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
```

Comment: I guess you rather meant something like:
Devices:  [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]